# How to find multiple sub string patterns in a string in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am trying to find multiple string patterns in a string in TCL. I cannot get the correct and optimized way to do that.

I have tried some code and it is not working

## I have to find -h ,-he,-hel ,-help in the string -help

```
set args "-help"
set res1 [string first "-h" $args] 
set res2 [ string first -he $args] 
set res3 [string first -hel $args]
set res4 [string first "-help" $args"]

if { $res1 == -1 || $res2 || $res3 || $res4 } {
   puts "\n string not found"
} else {
  puts "\n string found" 
}
```

how to use regexp here I am not sure , so need some inputs.

The expected output is

Comment: Welcome, Vyan. The snippet you posted is not valid, there is an excessive or unmatched double quote. Also, your question is not clear to me. Each `string first` does find the patterns you show, and returns the matching starting index into the haystack string (which is always `0` in your example, because, well, each pattern matches starting with index `0`). So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where using `regexp` is easier. (Asking if a string is a prefix of `-help` is a separate problem.) The trick here is to use `?` and `(…)` (or rather `(?:…)` which is the non-capturing version) in the RE *and* you must use the `--` option because the RE begins with a `-`:

```
if {[regexp -- {-h(?:e(?:lp?)?)?} $string]} {
    puts "Found the string"
} else {
    puts "Did not find the string"
}
```

If you want to know what string you actually found, add in a variable to pick up the overall match:

```
if {[regexp -- {-h(?:e(?:lp?)?)?} $string matched]} {
    puts "Found the string '$matched'"
} else {
    puts "Did not find the string"
}
```

If you instead want the indices where it matched, you need an extra option:

```
if {[regexp -indices -- {-h(?:e(?:lp?)?)?} $string match]} {
    puts "Found the string at $match"
} else {
    puts "Did not find the string"
}
```

---

If you were instead interested in whether the string was a prefix of `-help`, you instead should do:

```
if {[string equal -length [string length $string] $string "-help"]} {
    puts "Found the string"
} else {
    puts "Did not find the string"
}
```

Many uses of this sort of thing are actually doing command line parsing. In that case, the `tcl::prefix` command is *very* useful. For example, `tcl::prefix match` finds the entry in a list of options that a string is a unique prefix of and generates an error message when things are ambiguous or simply don't match; the result can be `switch`ed on easily:

```
set MY_OPTIONS {
    -help
    -someOtherOpt
}
switch [tcl::prefix match $MY_OPTIONS $string] {
    -help {
        puts "I have -help"
    }
    -someOtherOpt {
        puts "I have -someOtherOpt"
    }
}
```